# Missing home directory in ubuntu 14

Tags: directory, home-directory

I am running both windows and ubuntu in my computer. I accidentally formated a disk while logged in on widows but it did not contain ubuntu installation, when I tried to log in to ubutu later, I got the following error.

'The drive for /home is not ready yet or present.'

I tried to skip the process but I cant log to my user account, but am able to log in to guest account.

How can I recover my home directory and maybe reset to different disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the `/home` directory to a different disk by following the below steps.

- Boot from a Live CD/USB. Click on try to enter a live session.
- Open GParted and search your HDD from the list and format your **to-be** `/home` partition to EXT4
- Open terminal and type in the below command

`sudo blkid`

- This would list all the partitions in your system and you can note down the UUID of the partition which you want to assign as a `/home` directory
- Open Nautilus and mount the partition which was your `/` partition in your initial setup. Lets say it got mounted at `/media/<UUID>`. Here `<UUID>` refers to the UUID of your `/` partition
- Open terminal and make a copy of your fstab file

`cp /mnt/<UUID>/etc/fstab /mnt/<UUID>/etc/fstab.bak`

- Now edit the fstab file by `sudo nano /mnt/<UUID>/etc/fstab` and search for the line where you have the UUID of your previous `/home` partition and replace it with the UUID of the current one.

Reboot system and you should be good to go.

Comment: ahhh....with the comment, that everything that used to be in /home would no longer be present anymore including some package stuff that sometimes resides in /home.  Thus you can reformat and remount /home but you'll need to go to backups to get the appropriate content back.  Just creating the /home area, the system will probably work for the most part but there may be problems depending on the packages you exercise.